Tooltips in Tableau table
Overall, my goal is to have a tooltip for a table.
I have a simple table display in Tableau.
In the Rows I have a list of Offices and the count of cases (as discrete). This shows as a simple table or list if you will. I'd like to add a tooltip of the case details on hover.
For some reason, this setup does not allow for a tool tip. Even though there is a tooltip assigned in the Marks Card, nothing displays on hover.
If I have Offices in Columns and then have Case Count in Rows (as Continuous) I get a simple bar chart and the tool tip displays no problem. But once I move Offices to Rows and change Case Count to Discrete (to get that table view), tooltip is not showing.
Am I missing something or is this just how it is? Am I not able to put a tooltip on a simple table view? Thanks all! <3

When you have a discrete value on the rows shelf Tableau will read it as a "Header", and you'll normally see a grey 'Abc' to the right of it as there is no value currently displayed.
Bring [case count] from the rows shelf to the Text section of your marks pane as a discrete value. Add what you need to the Tooltip section and you should be good to go.
